# Highlight values on Sheet1 if matched on Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to highlight cells in sheet1 if they match the value in sheet2. Here is the code I have, there aren't any errors coming up but it does nothing. Basically I thought a Do while loop to go through all the records until it hit a blank and then it would read the cell value selected by my offset and compare it to the next sheets cell value while staying on the same row, and if it matched it would highlight on sheet 1 but if it didn't it would move on. Let me know how much I'm off here as I don't have much VBA knowledge. Thanks.

```
Public Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()

Dim resource As Range
Dim register As Range
Dim cancel As Range

Set resource = Worksheets("Resource List1").Cells(2, 4)
Set register = Worksheets("Registered List").Cells(2, 1)
Set cancel = Worksheets("Cancelled List").Cells(2, 1)


Call findRegister(resource, register)

End Sub

Public Sub findRegister(ByRef resource As Range, ByRef register As Range)

Dim i As Integer

i = 0

Do While resource.Offset(i, 3) <> ""

If resource.Offset(i, 3).Value = register.Range("A2").Value Then

resource.Offset(i, 3).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 37

End If

i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just use conditional formatting it seems like you just want to highlight any cells that aren't blank and match cell "A2" on another sheet.  Also note that register.range("A2") actually refers to Worksheets("Registered List").range("A3") since register is already a range that starts at A2.

Comment: yes, but I have different conditions I want to add later. so one sheet will have registered users, then a 3rd sheet will have cancelled users and when I try to use conditional formatting it got messy.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially correct, but I think you're having trouble with referencing the right cells. A good debugging technique would be to add `.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4` or something similar in your code to see visually whether you're referencing the proper cells. You can also put "F5", "F8", and breakpoints to good use in figuring out what's wrong. See http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html if you've never used these.

For example:

```
Do While resource.Offset(i, 3) <> ""  '<--Insert a breakpoint on this line,
                                      'then press "F8" to make sure the
                                      'code inside your Do While loop is
                                      'being executed

    resource.Offset(i, 3).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    register.Range("A2").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    If resource.Offset(i, 3).Value = register.Range("A2").Value Then

        resource.Offset(i, 3).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 40

    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something as simple as this . . . .

```
Sub Compare2Shts()
For Each Cell In Worksheets("CompareSheet#1").UsedRange
If Cell.Value <> Worksheets("CompareSheet#2").Range(Cell.Address) Then
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next

For Each Cell In Worksheets("CompareSheet#2").UsedRange
If Cell.Value <> Worksheets("CompareSheet#1").Range(Cell.Address) Then
Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next
End Sub
```